# BeautifulSoup Wildcard Search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I seem to be having a problem with BeautifulSoup. I simply can not figure out how to perform a search for a piece of text surrounded by more text, example:

String would be something like:

```
this is a stringoftext that I want.
```

and the code would be as follows:

```
print(soup.find_all(text="ofte"))
```

but this would just return "[]".

I have tried different variations of adding and removing *'s before and after "ofte" etc but to no avail and was wondering if I could get some help getting this to work.

I expect bs4 to be able to find the text that has been surrounded by other characters but it can not seem to locate it with different search parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a compiled regular expression object that matches the text you want to search for:

```
import re
print(soup.find_all(text=re.compile("ofte")))
```

Comment: Brilliant works a charm returns the whole string now. Just for readability would it be possible to just display the search term though?